I want my 2nd if-statement to do a recursion-type loop but it is not returning anything and defaulting to false, what am i doing wrong?
bool isPalindrome(string some_string) {
    if (some_string.length() == 0 || some_string.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (some_string[0] == some_string[some_string.length() - 1]) {
        return isPalindrome(some_string.substr(1, some_string.length() - 1));
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

First off, this code is to check if a string is palindrome or not. I looked up some links and thought I could use substr to get the characters after the first index and before the last character index, what am I doing wrong? This is my first time here so I'm sorry if this question was not well initiated.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?  Your debugger would show you the mistake quickly.

Tactical note: Making new strings can get really expensive. You're better off passing the string by reference and passing along with it the begin and end indices of the area of interest.

Add std::cout << some_string << '\n'; to the beginning of your function, and you will be able to see what some_string is, and that should tell you exactly what the issue is.

substr takes position and count (length), not start and end position. What does that tell you what you must pass as second argument?

Side note: some_string[0] == some_string[some_string.length() - 1] would be a bit more readable as some_string.front() == some_string.back().

Stack Overflow usage note: Give [ask] and Writing the Perfect Question a read-through.  Knowing what makes for a good question is much more effective than not knowing and apologizing.

Since there are answers for this specific question, I'll point out that recursion for a palindrome solver is not necessary.

The problem with your code is that substr() is being used in the wrong way. Here's a link to cppreference with full doc about this method. But in simple words, the problem is that the second argument of this method isn't the last index of the substring, but is the number of characters that should be included in the substring. So, in your second if, you call recursion with the same string, but without the first letter. So, for the string "abba", it will execute isPalindrome("bba") instead of isPalindrome("bb").
To do what you intended to do, you have to change this line:
return isPalindrome(some_string.substr(1, some_string.length() - 1));

to this instead:
return isPalindrome(some_string.substr(1, some_string.length() - 2));


For posterity, here is an implementation using iterators. Extremely cheap for long strings and very fast. As a bonus, it's only five lines of code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isPalindrome(std::string::const_iterator begin, std::string::const_iterator end) noexcept;

int main()
{
    std::string abba{"amanaplanacanalpanama"};
    return isPalindrome(std::cbegin(abba), std::cend(abba));
}

bool isPalindrome(std::string::const_iterator begin, std::string::const_iterator end) noexcept {
    if(begin == end) return true;
    if(end < begin) return false;
    const auto b = *begin;
    const auto e = *(end - 1);
    return (b == e) ? ( begin != (end - 1) ? isPalindrome(++begin, --end) : true) : false;
}

